# Flash Player 9 or 10+

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, statistics, flash

[Stats 1](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplatformruntimes/statistics.displayTab3.html) | [Stats 2](http://www.statowl.com/flash.php)

Looking at the statistics & considering I'm evil enough to forget about 5 % of the people of the world,

Will it be safe to move on to flash 10 (from currently 9), as a standard, in a website which gets roughly 1 million unique visits every month?

Is there anything else I should account for? What do the majority of the companies currently support as the minimum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use your statistics agent to check the Flash version penetration among your audience. With Google Analalytics, go to Audience, Technology, Browser and then Flash version. Make a decision with the accurate data instead of global stats.

Comment: It's not just for our website. Also as we don't use google analytics, we have already added our own version trackers. It's was more of a question about general market interest & the version it currently targets.

Comment: I guess it really depends on your audience. I have worked for companies where the update policy was middle-agish and every computer would stick to Flash 8. If you have a broad audience, since Flash automaticaly updates itself, you can target the last version.